# How to upload vimeo video from my server in php

Tags: php, api, vimeo

I am using vimeo api but i couldn't upload any video through their upload method that their documentation say

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    $client_identifier=REMOVED;
    $client_secret=REMOVED;        
    $check=$this->Accesstoken->find('all',array(
        'conditions'=> array('user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'))
    ));

    $access_token=$check[0]['Accesstoken']['vimeo_token'];

    $vim = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($client_identifier, $client_secret,$access_token);

    $video_uri=$vim->upload($this->request->params['form']['file_data']['tmp_name'], false);
    $metadata=array('name'=>'test11');
    $response=$vim->request($video_uri,$metadata,'PATCH');
}
```

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: No error @SagarGuhe its just keeping loading page

Comment: Make sure you don't post your client id and secrets to public locations! You should deactivate your application ASAP so that no one exploits the leak!

Comment: As for the upload, how large is the file, and what's your internet speed? If the page just keeps loading there is a chance that the file just takes some time. You might be able to debug more by uploading like this via the command line.